# prototypal inheritance (javascript)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

so I'm finally understanding prototype and how to use it.
I'm sure that I'm still trying to solve this as a java inheritance problem, so if there is a more prototypal way to go about this let me know.

If B inherits A I want B's constructor to first execute A's constructor. This is important for setting up B's local variables. At first I thought of doing something like

```
function B()
{
    B.prototype.constructor();
}
B.prototype = new A();
```

This of course does not work properly as it is essentially the same as saying

```
function B()
{
    new A();
}
```

Is there any way to actually extend a constructor in the java way?
Is there a better way to go about this?

{EDIT} I realized the problem was that I was trying to access private variables. I'm assuming private variables do not get passed down from prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy the A object into B's prototype you call A's constructor:

```
B.prototype = new A();
```

To setup A's local variables through the constructor arguments, you could do this:

```
B.prototype = new A(arguments, here);
```

Not sure if this answers your question though.

Answer (score -3):

You can use any Ajax framework that supports classes emulation, they handle classes and inheritance in javascript very well.
Also take a look at [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/).

Comment: Not sure about "any Ajax framework." jQuery doesn't add classes to JavaScript.